# How to set the affinity of a process from a Linux kernel mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, affinity

How can the CPU affinity of a process be set in kernel module?  In user mode there is a syscall `sched_setaffinity`, but I am looking for the kernel mode equivalent.

In the Linux kernel code, there is also a function called `sched_setaffinity`.  It's called from the `sys_sched_setaffinity` function which is called by `system_call`.  From what it seems, this is the function that I want to use.  The fact that it has the same name as the system call makes me a bit uneasy, though.

But as we all know, the best thing to do is to just try it.  So I did, and my module compiled.  However, when I try to load the module, it complains that the name `sched_setaffinity` is undefined.

Comment: Nor sure if it makes any difference, but do you want to set the affinity of an userland process, or of a kthread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sched_setaffinity` is not exported to modules.

If you modify `/usr/src/linux/kernel/sched.c`, you can cause `sched_setaffinity` to be exported to modules.

```
 long sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, const struct cpumask *in_mask)
 {
...
 }
+EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(sched_setaffinity);
```

Comment: That seems to be it.  Due to the nature of what I'm working on, it's not feasible to modify the kernel.  Still, thanks a lot.